# JavaScript carousel moves too quickly by itself

Tags: javascript, html

When I press the `next` or `previous` buttons or dots, the pictures start moving too quickly by themselves.  I cannot find the problem.

This is a carousel with four images and it's working, but not as it should.  I'm thinking the problem is in the JavaScript, but I could not identify it.

```js
var slideIndex = 1; 
showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}
  else if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length;}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += "active";
}
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();
function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" /> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleP.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>  
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <title>Smart Brothers</title>
  </head>
   <body>
   <div class="slideshow-container">
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="final.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Project One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="final2.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Project Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="final3.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Project Three</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="final4.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Project Four</div>
    </div> 
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got two functions with the same name. ---> `showSlides` That's not going to help.

Comment: Okay, so I should change the name of the function? Or what is your suggestions, please?

Comment: Without going in to details of multiple this wrong in this code, the specific thing that seems to control the timing of the slides is `setTimeout(showSlides, 3000);`

Comment: I'm still learning JavaScript =) It's working, but when I press buttons NEXT or PREVIOUS it's breaking and pictures start moving to quickly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your carousel moving quickly `JavaScript` supports `overriding` not `overloading`, meaning, that if you define two functions with the same name, the last one defined will `override` the previously defined version and every time a call will be made to the function, the last defined one will get executed.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides1();

function showSlides1() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides1, 3000);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleP.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
  <title>Smart Brothers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="final.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Project One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="final2.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Project Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="final3.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Project Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="final4.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Project Four</div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see now, thank you so much the problem is gone now.

Comment: if this helped mark the answer as accepted and upvote. and happy coding :)